# How to do type cast in spring integration expression

Tags: spring-integration

I'm experimenting with an existing project to use Spring Integration and the requirement is to dynamically call various service activators based on 'type' string value in the payload, And payload data has to be typecast in one of the service activator.

I thought I can do this in the expression like

> <service-activator input-channel="TEST_CHANNEL" expression="new  TestProcessor().test(**(mypackage.TestData)**payload.data)">

But this is giving expression parser error at the time of deployment
'EL1043E:(pos 156): Unexpected token. Expected 'rparen())' but was 'identifier'"

Here is the test case with more details and code..

Object data = requestItem.getData();
String type = requestType.getTypeName();

gatewayservice.processRequest(data,type)

```
<channel id="COMMON_REQUEST_PROCESSOR_CHANNEL"/>

<recipient-list-router id="routerGateway" input-channel="COMMON_REQUEST_PROCESSOR_CHANNEL">

  <recipient selector-expression="payload.type.equals('A')" channel="A_CHANNEL"/>

  <recipient selector-expression="payload.type.equals('B')" channel="B_CHANNEL"/>

  <recipient selector-expression="payload.type.equals('C')" channel="C_CHANNEL"/>

</recipient-list-router>

<channel id="A_CHANNEL"/>
<service-activator input-channel="A_CHANNEL"
        expression="new ClassA().process(payload.data)'">
</service-activator>

 <channel id="B_CHANNEL"/>
 <service-activator input-channel="B_CHANNEL" 
        expression="new ClassB().process(payload.data)'">
 </service-activator>

  <channel id="C_CHANNEL"/>
  <service-activator input-channel="C_CHANNEL" 
        expression="new ClassC().process((**specific class cast required here**)payload.data)'">
   </service-activator>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to cast in SpEL. In general it is type-free language.

What you are asking should work out-of-the-box.

Consider you have:

```
class TestProcessor {

    void test(Foo foo);

    void test(Bar bar);

}
```

The service-activator configuration like:

```
<service-activator input-channel="TEST_CHANNEL" 
          expression="new TestProcessor().test(payload.data)">
```

Should work as you expected.

Otherwise your question isn't clear, so, please, reconsider to rephrase it.

On the other hand there is always trick to use `<router>` and service-activators for particular cases.

Comment: Sorry, it is still isn't clear. Maybe more code and config for different services and their types? But again: SpEL does need casting

Comment: M-m. It still isn't clear why do you need cast there. Just let's come back to the cast purpose! We need it to increase object visibility via variable for code compilation . But the object is still the same of its origin type. So, if your method expects Foo , but object is Bar, you can't cast it anyway. SpEL choose method to call by the actual object type. Not sure how casting can help here. I don't tell you about converters, because you insist on casting. So, please describe the reason of casting there and how would you fix the problem just with Java

Comment: I had compilation in my mind and existing java code is doing typecasting which I'm removing with SI now. Thanks for your help.